# Firefox css height 100% problem. How to fix?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a table with div's in it's tds. Div's should fit all td's height.

Tds have `height: 1px;` 
And divs in tds have `height: 100%;`

here is link to the page http://websitebuilder.su/workfox/index.php

But in firefox this trick doesn't work. How can i make it work everywhere?

[chrome version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enL5A.jpg)

[firefox version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qph7d.jpg)

Comment: is it set to
``` div { display: block; }
```
?
Sample html&css would be helpful.

Comment: @WebMari it didn't help at all

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the style for the images to:

```
section.main_stages table td > div > div > img {
    /* margin-top: 15px; */
    /* margin-left: 8px; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 8px;
}
```

Float the enclosing div left and give it a position of relative:

```
section.main_stages table td > div > div {
    width: calc(100% - 42px - 4px );
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
    position: relative;
}
```

and get rid of the height 100%:

```
section.main_stages table td > div {
    width: auto;
    /* height: 100%; */
}
```

That seems to fix it in FireFox.

Comment: You might have an issue with scaling the images that way, but it does seem to work OK in FireFox and Chrome.